# How to download an image and show it in C# & ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to build a basic web app for accessing images I cant access normally. It works like this: let's say this image is not accessible on my network:

```
https://i.redd.it/n6y3rbn3qfm01.jpg
```

I will make a request to my app like this:

```
mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/Home/Mirror?url=https://i.redd.it/n6y3rbn3qfm01.jpg
```

And the controller will download the image and show it without client having to access i.reddit domain.

I tried doing this but it had 2 problems: it directly returns the file as download instead of showing it as an image in page and it only worked on my computer, not on Azure.

```
public ActionResult Mirror(String url)
{
    ViewBag.Url = url;

    Stream rtn = null;
    HttpWebRequest aRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse aResponse = (HttpWebResponse)aRequest.GetResponse();
    rtn = aResponse.GetResponseStream();

    return File(rtn, "image/jpeg", "Image_1");
}
```

Comment: what happens on Azure? do you get any error mesages/codes?

Comment: Try including a content type so the browser knows it's an image rather than just a generic file.

Comment: It just says An error occurred while processing your request

Comment: Or base64 encode it and return in a page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: I think problem is in getting the image from url in the first place.